# Converting a java project to JAR when it is dependent on another project (Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse

Lets say that there are two java projects P1 and P2 in my Eclipse IDE. P2 depends on P1, that is, it imports some of the classes in P1.

I am converting P2 to a JAR file. I see menus that I don't understand. I want to understand what the options mean and how to use them for my work. (Please refer to the corresponding numbers on the attached image)

1,2 - What are the .classpath and .project file ? How do I know if it belongs to P1 or P2 ?
3 - Given that P2 depends on P1, how do I decide which resources to export ?
4 - What does that mean ?

[image: Eclipse Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1,2 : these belong to the resource you have selected in the left hamd side menu
3: you could export both projects in a single jar too. But you can export each project indivisually , export to indivisual jars and then ise the two jars hence created.
4. This option will copy all output folders to jar. Output folders are basically folders where code is generated or copied. You can confirm output folder by going to buildpath->projects tab.